# REST API endpoint call of a single id gives other id results with similar begining alphabtes when called by name

Tags: mysql, django, api, rest

I am learning REST API Django and would appreciate your help in understaing the below case.

in `myproject/abcapp/forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields = "__all__"
       
  
class Zoo_data_2020Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Zoo_data_2020
        fields = "__all__"
```

in `myproject/abcapp/models.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class ProfileQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass

class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProfileQuerySet(self.model,using=self._db)


class Profile(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,max_length=200) 
    subtype=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  
    objects = ProfileManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'

        managed = False
        db_table ='profiles'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
          
      
class Zoo_data_2020QuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass
  
class Zoo_data_2020Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Zoo_data_2020QuerySet(self.model,using=self._db)

class Zoo_data_2020(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    size=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=100000000)
    weight=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=100000000)
    age=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=100000000)
    
    objects = Zoo_data_2020Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'zoo_data_2020'
        verbose_name_plural = 'zoo_data_2020s'

        managed = False
        db_table ='zoo_data_2020'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

in `myproject/abcapp/api/views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins, permissions
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json
from abcapp.models import *
from .serializers import *


def is_json(json_data):
    try:
        real_json = json.loads(json_data)
        is_valid = True
    except ValueError:
        is_valid = False
    return is_valid


class ProfileDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []
    queryset= Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'


class ProfileAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes= []
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    passed_id = None
    search_fields = ('id','name','animal')
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()


    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Profile.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs=qs.filter(name__icontains=query)
        return qs


  
class Zoo_data_2020DetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []
    queryset= Zoo_data_2020.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Zoo_data_2020Serializer
    lookup_field = ('id','name')
 

class Zoo_data_2020APIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes =[]
    authentication_classes= []
    serializer_class = Zoo_data_2020Serializer

    passed_id = None
    search_fields = ('id','name')
    queryset = Zoo_data_2020.objects.all()


    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Zoo_data_2020.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs=qs.filter(name__icontains=query)
        return qs
```

in `myproject/abcapp/api/serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from abcapp.models import *
 
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields = "__all__"
        
        read_only_fields = ['name']

class Zoo_data_2020Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Zoo_data_2020
        fields = "__all__"
        
        read_only_fields = ['name']
```

So when i call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/zoodata2020/?search=AKE` it gives me information about `AKE` but also information about **name** `AKELA` which is also in `zoodata2020` table. What to do so that i only get information about `AKE` ?

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "AKE",
        "subtype": "beaver",
        "type": "arctic",
        "gender": "female",
   
       
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "AKELA",
        "subtype": "wolf",
        "type": "arctic",
        "gender": "male",
   
       
    }
]
```

So i need only id **7** but not **19** and i call by `name`. The same issue when i call by **http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/zoodata2020/?search=24** it lists me **id 24,224,2424**. Even if i call `.../?search=24,24` it would give id 2424. Though it should return:

```
HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "detail": "Not found."
}
```

But it does not. Where i need to look and what i need to fix and how.

So tried to do changes in `qs=qs.filter(name__icontains=query)` to `qs=qs.filter(name__exact=query)` but ut still does not work.

Would appreciate if you could help to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

`qs=qs.filter(name__icontains=query)` line performs a pattern matching filtering. If you need exact filtering, then use `__exact` postfix instead of `__contains`:

```
qs=qs.filter(name__exact=query)
```

Comment: i did as you advised, it still lists all id/names that have AKE at the begining, middle and end

Comment: You have the same line at multiple places in your vode. Did you replace all instances?

Comment: what do you mean the 'same line' ?

Comment: The same line of fode that searches for contain instead of exact.

Comment: i replaced in all instances but it still does not work